Control how many digits are printed for an astropy quantity in a jupyter notebook
I use astropy to make calculations with units and I normally do these calculations in a jupyter notebook so the results are printed nicely. I would like to know how to control the number of digits that are displayed in the notebook. Take a look at this example:

The speed of light is defined to be exactly "c = 29,979,245,800 cm/s". However, when I print const.c.cgs in a cell, I get "2.9979246 x 10^10 cm/s". It rounded it up. I know that the exact value is indeed stored in that constant as can be seen by printing it or accessing its value directly (e.g. print(const.c.cgs) or simply const.c.cgs.value which gives the exact value "29979245800 cm/s"), but it displays it with rounding up. I understand this behavior and it's fine for most cases, but there are cases like this where I'd like to see more digits. How can I change the number of digits that are printed in the cell? I want to have this pretty printing of jupyter, but I want to see the full value too.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. Provide as much of your code and output as possible as code-formatted text in an [edit], and reserve images for anything that can't be represented as such.

@AndrewYim This is exactly a situation where an image is more useful than the code. My question is about the visual display of the results in a jupyter notebook. The code is very short and not very important for this question.

The visual output is fine as an image, but the code and textual output should be text, imo. And honestly, I think you would be okay writing the pretty-print output as "2.9979246 x 10^10 cm/s" - even though it's not exactly accurate, it's useful just by virtue of being text, which is good for all the reasons explained in that post.

Google on astropy quantity format (for future reference) and then see:
https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/units/format.html
